# Not able to open the file which is downloaded from the byte[] in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to downlaod a file in a specified path in a device from the byte[]. I am able to see the documents in that path but not able to open them. When I try to open them it is showing the file  can not be opend alert.

I am using the following code to download.

```
  public async Task WriteBytesToFile(byte[] fileBytes, string fileFullPath)
    {
         string pathToNewFolder = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "Test");

        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToNewFolder);

        File.WriteAllBytes(fileFullPath,fileBytes);
    }
```

Comment: how  are  you trying to open them?   Is it throwing  an exception?

Comment: There are no exceptions while downloading the file. The file is saved in the downloads directory. But if i try to open the file by tapping it, it is showing file can not be opend in android.

Comment: There are no exceptions while downloading the file. The file is saved in the downloads directory. But if i try to open the file by tapping it, it is showing file can not be opend in android.

Comment: you are not saving with any file extension so I'd guess that Android has no way of knowing the file type and which app to use  to open it

Comment: The fileFullPath contains the path and the extension in it.

Comment: Do I have to specify any other where also..

Comment: fileBytes=/storage/emulated/0/test/dummy.pdf, This is the path I am trying to open

Comment: does your device have a PDF app installed?

Comment: Yes, It is installed. I can open other pdf files in my device.

Comment: is it a valid pdf?  Can you copy it  to your desktop and open it?

Comment: Please have a look at this link https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows